# Differentiating Windows CE barcode scanners with javascript

Tags: javascript, barcode-scanner

I am using the built in web browser on the scanner to access a javascript page with an auto focused form. It redirects the standard output stream to the form and submits it which puts the barcode into a database. Is there any ways I can get some kind of unique information regarding the barcode scanner from this page? This way I can differentiate between scanner entries?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, basically you are just wanting to be able to distinguish between web page visitors, and maintain that unique distinction of visitors going forward (i.e. barcode device "1" will always be barcode device "1" when that particular device visits your page).

Can you not just do this with [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)?  That is, just assign each barcode device a non-expiring cookie, store the cookie on the client device, and maintain that cookie / device relationship in your database going forward.  Then, each time a form is submitted, you will know which device made the submission by checking the value of the cookie.